# Google sign in issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, google-signin

i have installed  pod 'Google/SignIn' framework in my project. I have integrated client ID and all the stuffs provided by google Docs, the problem is when i hit google sign in button its takes me to google SignIn page in there i entering my username and password after i hit submit button the page its not redirect to my App its still in google page and its not returning any values from Google page

here my sample code :

```
@IBAction func socialAction(sender: AnyObject) {
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "************.apps.googleusercontent.com"
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let name = user.profile.name
            let email = user.profile.email

            print("gmail==>\(email)")
            // ...
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}
```

in AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        var options: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: sourceApplication!,
            UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: annotation]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)


       }
```

Comment: follow this link http://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/

Comment: i getting warning as code after 'return' will never be executed

Comment: After trying all the Answer now its not opening google signing page itself

Comment: bro its working whenever i delete app in simulator and run again means its working, now i can't fetch user info after i redirect from google signin

Comment: bro can anyone help me out everything is working good but i can't fetch the user information \

Answer (score 2):

r u handling url in app delegate? and try this if you are not handling.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

 return  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation) || FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: i getting warning as code after 'return' will never be executed

Comment: because first line of function will return either true or false(true if the url was intended for the Facebook SDK, false if not.) or it google plus handleurl line never get executed .

Comment: bro its still working for Facebook only. when i try for google no action is doing

Comment: try this. and did you  add values in urlschems in urltype? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating#add_url_schemes_to_your_project

Comment: bro ur code is working to open and redirect to fb when i try for google its not taking me to google page to signin its in same view controller

Comment: bro its working whenever i delete app in simulator and run again means its working, now i can't fetch user info after i redirect from google signin

Comment: does it return all info like email, first name last name all ?

Comment: open GIDGoogleUser and GIDProfileData class , you will get all info.

Comment: if you're delegate are not calling, write this in your view controller
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

Comment: it should be work. can you share your complete code to me? i'll check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107031/discussion-between-sahil-and-user3458924).

Comment: my app size is crossed 160 mb due to many frameworks i have installed

Answer (score 1):

Add the URL scheme. For more details

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#step_3_add_a_url_type

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application   openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url  sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation])
    {
        return YES;

    }
    return NO;
}
```

this code is perfectly working in objective c.

Comment: yes you are rite but i have already integrated FBSDK also its not accepting see my updated question

Comment: missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool' this the error message aim getting while i paste ur code can u check it\

Comment: in return what i should call ?

Comment: bro its still opening for Facebook not not working google sign in

Comment: when i hit Facebook button its takes me to fb page, while i hit google signing button nothing is happened, i dono what happened

Comment: bro its working whenever i delete app in simulator and run again means its working, now i can't fetch user info after i redirect from google signin

Comment: no error bro its worked but i can't able to fetch user info like email, first name last name like that'

Comment: then what are you getting in GIDGoogleUser in delegate method

Comment: that method itself not calling i checked with breakpoint but its not calling